# How do I stop setInterval from running in a case block

Tags: javascript, node.js, switch-statement, user-input

```js
            var text = //string from user input
            switch (text) {
            case 'yes':
                var myint = setInterval(async () => {
                    //do something
                }, 1000);
                break;
            case 'stop':
                clearInterval(myint)
                break;
            case 'no':
                console.log('ok')
                break;
            default:
                console.log('hi');
            }
```

This code takes user input, converts it into a string and passes it into the switch statement
As seen in the snippet above, when `text = 'yes'`, the interval starts. But when the user inputs no i.e `text = 'no'` to run clear interval, the interval doesn't stop. How do I this with or without `setInterval`?

Comment: The `myint` is scoped as a var, meaning it's going to only exist within the context of the method it is called in, and only for that instance of the function run.  If you need to reference a previously created interval in future method runs, you need to change the scope of the variable so it persists through runs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare var before of the case scope.

```
var text = "userinput";
// declare globally
var myint;

switch (text) {
case 'yes':
    var myint = setInterval(async () => {
        //do something
    }, 1000);
    break;
case 'stop':
    clearInterval(myint)
    break;
case 'no':
    console.log('ok')
    break;
default:
    console.log('hi');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```js
var myint;
document.querySelector("select").onchange = function() {
  var text = this.value, i = 0;
  switch(text) {
    case 'yes':
      myint = setInterval(async () => {
        console.log(++i);
      }, 1000);
      break;
    case 'no':
      clearInterval(myint);
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="no">No</option>
  <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi. It doesn't work for me for some reason in Node. I am using it to send a repeated proactive message to a user on microsoft's Bot Framework on receiving input. I am trying to subsequently stop the message. It just keeps sending